# Rendering new custom html templates in existing Django project

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-templates

I'm not a Django expert but I need to make customizations of [this software](https://github.com/openvinotoolkit/cvat/tree/develop/cvat) which is written in Django using the rest framework.

I need to render a custom html template let's say `a.html`, however when I go to `http://localhost:8080/custom/custom/a` I get redirected back to different page - not `a.html`.

This is what I've done so far. I created a new folder in **apps** called **custom**:

```
cvat
    apps
        custom
            templates
                custom
                   _init.py
                   a.html, b.html, ...
            urls.py
```

**apps.py**

```
from django.apps import AppConfig

class CustomConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'cvat.apps.custom'
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('custom/<str:name>', views.CustomView),
]
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def CustomView(request, name):
    return render(request, 'custom/'+name+'.html')
```

In addition, I have modified these existing files to add the `custom` folder that was created in `apps`:

in [urls.py](https://github.com/openvinotoolkit/cvat/blob/develop/cvat/urls.py#L27) added my url patterns:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('cvat.apps.engine.urls')),
    path('django-rq/', include('django_rq.urls')),
    path('custom/', include('cvat.apps.custom.urls')),
]
```

in [base.py](https://github.com/openvinotoolkit/cvat/blob/develop/cvat/settings/base.py#L129) added this:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
...
    'cvat.apps.custom'
]
```

Any advice on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Where exactly do you get redirected?

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

url can be like this

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('custom/<name>/', views.CustomView),
]
```

and your view should be like this.

```
def CustomView(request, name):
    return render(request, f'custom/{name}.html')
```

Hope this will help you.